# Row data undefined after reinitializing the datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

What I am trying to do is filter my datatable when a user checks the check box. While the filtering is working properly but there is a view button in datatable which show the row data.

When the page loads everything works fine but I check the checkbox which reinitializes datatable and click on the view button it gives me error undefined. View code doesn't work after a reinitialization of the datatable.

```js
var url = 'blah/blah/';
gettable(url);
$("input[name='showclose']").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    url = 'bah/blah?show=true';
    gettable(url);
  } else {
    url = 'blah/blah/';
    gettable(url);
  }
})

//datatable and ajax code
function drawtable(response) {
  $('#names_table').DataTable().clear().destroy();
  table = $('#names_table').dataTable({
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aaData": response,
    "destory": true,
    "pageLength": 25,
    "columns": [{
        "data": "date",
        "render": function(data) {
          var date = new Date(data);
          return (date.toDateString());
        }
      }, {
        "data": "job_id"
      }, {
        "data": "customer.user.username"
      }, {
        data: null,
        className: "dt-center editor-edit",
        defaultContent: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></button>',
        orderable: false
      }
    }]
  });

//Modal view
// var table = $('#names_table').DataTable();
//getactionbtn()
var table = $('#names_table').DataTable();

$('#names_table tbody').on('click', '.editor-edit', function() {
  tid = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
  console.log(table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data());
});

function gettable(s) {
  $('#dettable').hide();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: base_url + s,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    success: function(response) {
      drawtable(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Is that a typo at the url-path in `if (this.checked)`/in both? - It differs to the initial url.

Comment: It was typing error while typing question